# Trouble setting up GZWeb

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all:
Installed gazebo2 (limited by ROS deployment), and was attempting to get gzweb up and running.
Running into the following when running `./deploy.sh -m`

```
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/specter7/gzweb/build
Scanning dependencies of target gzcoarse
[100%] Building CXX object tools/CMakeFiles/gzcoarse.dir/gzcoarse.cc.o
Linking CXX executable gzcoarse
[100%] Built target gzcoarse
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
There are node-gyp build errors, exiting.
```

This binary file exists and has the permissions which permit it to be read.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12210/trouble-setting-up-gzweb/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2015-12-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This looks like one of the questions in the [troubleshooting](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=gzweb_install&cat=gzweb#Troubleshooting) section of the installation tutorial.

The suggested solution is to add a symlink from `nodejs` to `node`:

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2015-12-16**:
Not sure how I missed the trouble shooting section... thank you